# Is there any way to remove or replace the pre-rendered cut scenes from my installation?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo 3 comes with a number of cut scenes, and as well put together as they are, I don't really intend to watch them multiple times. I've got Diablo 3 on an SSD, so if there's a way to remove these from my installation completely it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do know you can stop them from playing with `esc`, right? Is that not good enough?

Comment: @QAvenDreamer the point is also to cut down on space

Comment: @Mr.November What you can do is moving large files to another partition or hard disk and replacing them with a symlink in the Diablo III folder. For more information see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link). [This](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html) is a good shell extension for symlink/junction point creation. Other tools like [Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover/) do the same.

Comment: @speakr Thanks! I had forgotten about symlinks, despite the fact that I use them for some Steam games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, no. While you can delete the 1.5 GB `enUS_Cutscene.mpq` file from your installation directory, it will get re-created once you launch the game.

(Despite this, however, it seems that the cutscenes aren't actually *downloaded* again. Doing something that triggers a cutscene or watching one from the main menu will instead stream a low-res version of it from Blizzard's servers, YouTube-style.)

Comment: Harumph. Though, I guess it's only 1.5GB. For some reason I thought it was more.

Comment: Fun fact: 1.5GB is the size of the entire 3-disc Diablo II install, a third of which was video. My, how times have changed...

Comment: Has anyone tried *replacing* the file with another file that is significantly smaller?  Might have different results.